# how to add color, when my link (icofont) is active angular in 4?

Tags: css, angular, navbar

```
<div>
  <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12  filter-bar">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded m-b-30">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right" >
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link icon-list-demo" data-toggle="tab" [routerLink]="['/franchise/customer/details/dashboard']" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" ngbTooltip="Dashboard"><i class="icofont icofont-chart-pie-alt"></i></a>
          <div class="slide"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link icon-list-demo active" data-toggle="tab" [routerLink]="['/franchise/customer/details/users']" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" ngbTooltip="Users"><i class="icofont icofont-users-alt-5"></i></a>
          <div class="slide"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ">
          <a class="nav-link icon-list-demo" data-toggle="tab" [routerLink]="['/franchise/customer/details/cabinets']" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" ngbTooltip="Cabinets"><i class="icofont icofont-cubes"></i></a>
          <div class="slide"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link icon-list-demo" data-toggle="tab" [routerLink]="['/franchise/customer/details/inventory']" role="tab" aria-expanded="true" ngbTooltip="Inventory"><i class="icofont icofont-card"></i></a>
          <div class="slide"></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

my css

```
.navbar-light .navbar-nav > .active > a > i,{
color: #64b0f2;
background-color: transparent;
}
```

How to highlight the icofont, when it is active, as you can see above I have icofont inside my link, i am not able to change its color when it is in active state

Comment: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive Read this document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angular 4 router give a way to add a class when link is active, 
here is the example

```
<a routerLink="/link" routerLinkActive="active">link</a>
```

now when link route comes it automatically add active class in anchor tag, now you can do what you want to do with that,

Comment: this works fine to create active. but my css color is not staying on it when i am in that link, the color comes only once when i click the link

Comment: the problem is that, you styling is want "active" class in li, but you gave class to anchor tag, 
below is previously asked question. solve your problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46447371/how-to-make-parent-state-activei-e-add-active-class-when-child-is-active

Answer (score 1):

Try use `.navbar-light .navbar-nav > .active > a > i:after` or `.navbar-light .navbar-nav > .active > a > i:before` i guess your icon create with css in after/before parameters.
And make sure that you have the correct path to the tag to set active.